# Why is my latitude always 0?

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters

    // UI elements
    //private TextView lblLocation;
    //private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates;
    public String stringLat;
    public double latitude;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }

        if(mLastLocation != null){
            latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        }

        //Testing testing = new Testing();

        Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + latitude);
        //Log.w("Longitude is: ", getCurrentLocation.lgt);
        //Log.d("TestingTestingTag", "Value: " + testing.getTestingNum());








    }

    protected void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            //lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
            stringLat = String.valueOf(latitude);

        } else {

            //lblLocation
            //.setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating google api client object
     * */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     * */
    protected boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }



}
```

I tested it in real device with location services on. Why is my latitude always showing 0 in logcat ?What is wrong ? I want to get the latitude of my current location.

03-08 00:34:02.950  14159-14159/com.example.user.stuff D/ADebugTag﹕ Value: 0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS gets the value of your last known location in **`onConnected()`** method, while you are trying to get last known location's value inside `onCreate()` method which will definitely return 0.

Write `Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + latitude);` inside `displayLocation()` method which is invoked by `onConnected()` method.